# What does this "all other dung" mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Later, Cato the Elder recommended that Romans “save carefully goat,
>   sheep, cattle, and all other dung.
>
> [Source](http://www.newyorker.com/arts/critics/books/2013/10/21/131021crbo_books_kolbert?currentPage=all)

Does this mean **goat's, sheep's, cattle's and all other animals' dung**?

Comment: Yes, you've got it.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question, which illustrates both the difficulty of translation and some characteristic English-language patterns.

In the original Latin from which this is translated, *Caprinum, ovillum, bubulum, item ceterum stercus*, Cato employs adjectives modifying *stercus*:

- caprinum, “of or pertaining to goats”
- ovillum, “of or pertaining to sheep”
- bubulum, “of or pertaining to cows or cattle”

These align comfortably with the following adjective *ceterum*, “other”.

We have adjectives with approximately these meanings in English—*caprine*, *ovine*, *bovine*—but they are pretty much confined to scientific and technical writing and don’t really suit Cato’s straightforward style. We also have adjectives like *sheepish* and *goatish* and could build *cowish* by analogy; but *sheepish* and *goatish* have very different meanings today, and *cowish* would stand out as a coinage—again, not suitable to Cato’s style.

So the Loeb translator elects the natural way to express this in English, which is to employ attributive nouns: *goat dung*, *sheep dung*, *cattle dung*. And, following Cato's pattern, he eliminates repetition by dropping all but the last *dung*: *goat, sheep, cattle dung*.

So far, so good. But now he's got a problem. *Other* **can** act as a noun; but in front of a noun it is always understood as an adjective. Consequently, following Cato's literal pattern creates an awkward non-parallelism: noun, noun, noun, and adjective ... and that odd pattern trips you up. It leaves you suspended between the ordinary meaning (Cato's meaning) of *other* as an adjective and the implied meaning of *other* as a noun meaning “other animal”.

My own inclination would be to ignore Cato's structure, which cannot be gracefully matched in English, and go for a straightforward expression of the meaning, which doesn’t really depend on an adjectival sense for *ceterum*:

> Carefully save the dung of goats, sheep, cattle and anything else.  *OR*
>   Carefully save goat dung, sheep dung, cattle dung, and any other dung. *OR*
>   Carefully save your dung—goat, sheep, cattle or anything else.

As the Duchess says, “Take care of the sense and the sounds will take care of themselves.”

Comment: How about "Carefully save caprine, ovine, bovine, and all other waste."?  Maybe not graceful or commonly heard, but I just wanted to offer it for curiosity's sake.  Compare with "Quickly eat yellow, blue, pink, and all other jellybeans.".